# Spring Polymorphic Properties: CustomBindHandler works but not for Lists

Tags: spring-properties

I have a bunch of entities, I would like to load from the `application.yaml` file. The structure seems rather complex but it is as it is and that includes polymorphism with some classes:

This is the base structor for the properties I want to load:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "groups")
@Data
public class GroupsServiceProperties {
    private List<GroupProperties> groups;
    private List<AggregateProperties> aggregates;
}
```

```
@Data
public class GroupProperties {
    private String id;  
    private Map<String, String> labels; 
    private SelectorProperties selector;    
}
```

```
@Data
public class AggregateProperties {
    private String id;
    private String type;
    private Map<String, String> labels;
    private SelectorProperties selector;
    
}
```

And this is where the interesting part is:

```
@Data
public class SelectorProperties {
    private String type;
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class LabelSelectorProperties extends SelectorProperties {
    private String name;
    private Operator operator;
    private String value;
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class CompositeSelectorProperties extends SelectorProperties {
    private Operator operator;
    private List<SelectorProperties> selectors;
}
```

Now let me give some example of YAML that I want to load:

```
groups:
  groups:
  - id: office
    labels:
      name: Office
    selector:
      type: LabelSelector
      name: room
      operator: EQUALS
      value: office
  - id: all_power
    labels:
      name: Power
    selector:
      type: CompositeSelector
      operator: AND
      selectors:
      - type: LabelSelector
        name: property
        operator: EQUALS
        value: power
  aggregates:
  - id: indoor_temperature
    type: QuantityAggregate
    labels:
      name: Indoor Temperature
    selector:
      type: CompositeSelector
      operator: AND
      selectors:
      - type: LabelSelector
        name: area
        operator: EQUALS
        value: indoor
      - type: LabelSelector
        name: device
        operator: EQUALS
        value: sensor
      - type: LabelSelector
        name: property
        operator: EQUALS
        value: temperature
```

So there are two `GroupProperties` in `groups.groups` and one `AggregateProperties` in `groups.aggregates`.

The first `GroupProperties` works, since it is referencing a `LabelSelectorProperties` directly. The `LabelSelectorProperties` instance has all the values.

The second `GroupProperties` does NOT work. What I get is an instance of `CompositeSelector` with a `SelectorProperties` instead of `LabelSelectorProperties`.

The same is the case for the `AggregateProperties` in the list.

So it looks like, my `BindHandler` is working unless when it comes to lists. Is that possible?

```
@Component
public class CustomBindHandlerAdvisor implements ConfigurationPropertiesBindHandlerAdvisor {
    
    @Override
    public BindHandler apply(BindHandler bindHandler) {
        return new CustomBindHandler(bindHandler);
    }

}

public class CustomBindHandler extends AbstractBindHandler {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomBindHandler.class);
    
    private final Map<String, Class<? extends SelectorProperties>> configClasses = new HashMap<>();

    
    public CustomBindHandler(BindHandler parent) {
        super(parent);
        configClasses.put("LabelSelector", LabelSelectorProperties.class);
        configClasses.put("CompositeSelector", CompositeSelectorProperties.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object onSuccess(ConfigurationPropertyName name, Bindable<?> target, BindContext context, Object result) {
        if (result instanceof SelectorProperties) {
            SelectorProperties config = ((SelectorProperties) result);
            if (configClasses.containsKey(config.getType())) {
                Class<? extends SelectorProperties> aClass = configClasses.get(config.getType());
                BindResult<? extends SelectorProperties> r = context.getBinder().bind(name, Bindable.of(aClass));
                return r.get();
            } else {
                logger.error("unable to bind type {}", config.getType());
            }
        }
        return super.onSuccess(name, target, context, result);
    }
}
```

I added a `System.out` to the `onSuccess` method of the `CustomBindHandler` to see which properties it is actually consulted for. It never gets asked for `groups.aggregates[0].selector.selectors[0]` which is what I would expect.

```
groups.aggregates[0].id
groups.aggregates[0].labels.name
groups.aggregates[0].labels
groups.aggregates[0].selector.type
groups.aggregates[0].selector
groups.aggregates[0].type
groups.aggregates[0]
groups.aggregates
groups.groups[0].id
groups.groups[0].labels.name
groups.groups[0].labels
groups.groups[0].selector.type
groups.groups[0].selector
groups.groups[0]
groups.groups[1].id
groups.groups[1].labels.name
groups.groups[1].labels
groups.groups[1].selector.type
groups.groups[1].selector
groups.groups[1]
groups.groups[2].id
groups.groups[2].labels.name
groups.groups[2].labels
groups.groups[2].selector.type
groups.groups[2].selector
groups.groups[2]
groups.groups[3].id
groups.groups[3].labels.name
groups.groups[3].labels
groups.groups[3].selector.type
groups.groups[3].selector
groups.groups[3]
groups.groups
groups
```

What do I need to do to make this work for the list in `CompositeSelector`?

EDIT: I created a demo to illustrate the problem here: https://github.com/mathias-ewald/spring-configuration-properties-list-of-polymorphic-types

Comment: According to this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16444 it's not possible